# CSS not working in chromium. changing child from parent hover

Tags: css, chromium

I'm having a problem displaying the next code in chromium:

Version 28.0.1500.71 Ubuntu 13.04 (28.0.1500.71-0ubuntu1.13.04.1)

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
    Box text
</div> 
</div>


.parent {
border-bottom: 9px solid blue;
}
.parent:hover .child{
border-bottom: 9px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jq6uj/

It's fine in firefox and chrome.

Should I send a ticket?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you include the following code as well: `.child{border-bottom:0;}` ? I don't have a similar setup so I can't reproduce the error, just guessing :)

Comment: Same thing.....Could you try opening jsfiddle in your google crhome? Can you reproduce the error?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chromium 30.0.1599.114 Ubuntu 13.10 (30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.10.2)

Comment: I updated to Version 31.0.1650.63 Ubuntu 13.04 (31.0.1650.63-0ubuntu0.13.04.1~20131204.1) and the border is not being replaced but added above.

Comment: @wwglobers Yes. That's what it does for me too. Also in Firefox and Rekonq. You should explain exactly what you want instead of saying you "have a problem".

Comment: Perhaps it's not about the browser, it's that the code is erroneous.

Comment: Sorry, I want the border to be replaced, not added. Replace the border color.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you only want to replace the blue border with a red one you should use `.parent:hover{border-bottom:9px solid red;}` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, I'm sorry for the inconvenients,In my real code it's something muddled so I'm trying to change it not to need to replace the child but the parent. I don't know why I saw it working in firefox and chrome once. Thanks you for your time guys, I will award you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a browser bug. There is nowhere that you are telling it to delete the original border on mouse over. So do something like this:

```
.parent:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jq6uj/1/)

Or as WP_ said, simply set the border color to be red on hover instead of using the child element if that's possible.